# How would indexes improve aggregate lookup speeds in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm building a virtual currency system, and as it is situated in real money, accurate retention of data is a very key goal. I am building my currency so that user wallets do not have a fixed value (an 'amount'), rather, they are the net of all transactions to and from that wallet -- sort of like bitcoin.

So, if I'm calculating the amount of a wallet, my MySQL query looks like this.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`tx`.`amount`), 0)
    FROM `transactions` AS `tx`
    WHERE `tx`.`to_wallet_id` = 5
) - (
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`tx`.`amount`), 0)
    FROM `transactions` AS `tx`
    WHERE `tx`.`from_wallet_id` = 5
) AS `net`
```

This query builds a `net` value using the aggregate data of a `SUM()` for all transactions *towards* a wallet subtracted by all transactions *from* a wallet. The final value represents how much money the wallet currently contains.

**In short, I want to know** how I can optimize my table so that these queries are very fast and scale as well possible.

I would assume I should index `[from_wallet_id, amount]` and `[to_wallet_id, amount]`, but I'm very uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do the following:

- Make amount field is not nullable. And put 0 as default value.
- Create indexes according to you idea (`[from_wallet_id, amount]` and `[to_wallet_id, amount]`). At allows to run queries which retrieves all necessary data from indexes.

If it doesn't help, you can think about the following options:

- Divide the transaction table on 2 part: in_transaction and out_transaction
- Keep aggregate values in the separate table and update its after any changes.